# Deploy to artifactory via python script

Tags: python, deployment, py2exe, artifactory, artifact

I am trying to create a python script that can deploy an artifact to Artifactory. 
I am using Python 3.4 and I want the resulted script to put it through py2exe, so external libraries might create issues.

Through all my research, I found that one way is this, but I don't know how to "translate" it to Python:

```
curl -X PUT -u user:password --data-binary @/absolute/path/my-utils-2.3.jar "http://localhost/artifactory/my-repo/my/utils/2.3/"
```

How can I achieve that into Python? Or is it any either way for deploying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Been trying the whole day and I've had some successful testing using the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

```
import requests

url = "repo/path/test.txt"

    file_name = "test.txt"
    auth=(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    
  
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as fobj:
        res = requests.put(url, auth=auth, data=fobj)
        print(res.text)
        print(res.status_code)
```

And py2exe had no issues with it.

Comment: is there anyway to use it using pycurl?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take look at [Party](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Party), either look on how they do it, or just use it directly.

Comment: from what I see they only get, they don't put (deploy)